# Can you use Bing Maps in offline editing in the ArcGIS Collector app?

Tags: basemap, arcgis-online-basemaps, arcgis-collector

Is it possible to use Bing Maps in the offline mode in the ArcGIS Collector app? In ArcGIS collector can I download the map, work offline and sync my edits when I'm using Bing aerials as my base map?  I know that this is possible when using ESRI published aerials and base maps but what about Bing Maps.  I have tested this and I don't have the option to download the map for offline use when using Bing Maps but I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing.  I already have the Bing Key registered and setup for use in my organizational account so that's not the issue.  Has anyone had success using Bing Maps offline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately it's not possible to take Bing Maps "offline".

Read about it [here in the FAQ](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/faq.htm#anchor59).